# Latest/previous ver return error "The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long."

Tags: visual-studio, coverlet

Try to install latest ver (3.1.0) of coverlet.msuild using nuget package manager for C# Unit Test Project on VS 2019 Community.
I am return the error:
"The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long.  C:\Users\robpi\source\repos\UnitTestProject1\packages\coverlet.msbuild.3.1.0\build\coverlet.msbuild.targets

coverlet.msbuild does not install

Note: I try to install earlier version (2.7.0) - same outcome

Comment: I am having the same problem with .NET framework 4.8. For .NET core it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In you project file / packages file replace the value 3.1.0 by another value already present in you cache folder, save and reload your project.
From there you should able to work and, eventually update the package.